# Django REST Framework (ModelViewSet), 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Tags: python, angularjs, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a REST API to register new users, I'm using Django REST Framework and calling the API using AngularJS:

when I call the API using POST method I'm getting this error:

> Method Not Allowed (POST): /api/v1/accounts

Here is my code:

### for the Server side

views.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets, status, views
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from authentication.serializers import AccountSerializer
from authentication.permissions import IsAccountOwner
from rest_framework.response import Response
from authentication.models import Account
import json


class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        if self.request.method == "POST":
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)
            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad Request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with received data'
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serialisers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from rest_framework import serializers
from authentication.models import Account


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'tagline', 'password',
                  'confirm_password',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)

        def create(validated_data):
            return Account.objects.create(**validated_data)

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
            instance.tagline = validated_data.get('tagline', instance.tagline)

            instance.save()

            password = validated_data.get('password', None)
            confirm_password = validated_data.get('confirm_password', None)

            if password and confirm_password and password == confirm_password:
                instance.set_password(password)
                instance.save()

            update_session_auth_hash(self.context.get('request'), instance)

            return instance
```

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsAccountOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, account):
        if request.user:
            return account == request.user
        return False
```

urls.py

```
from authentication.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from posts.views import AccountPostsViewSet, PostViewSet
from authentication.views import AccountViewSet
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from CVC.views import IndexView

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)
router.register(r'posts', PostViewSet)
accounts_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(
    router, r'accounts', lookup='account'
)

accounts_router.register(r'posts', AccountPostsViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/auth/login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^api/v1/auth/logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(accounts_router.urls)),
```

and for the client side:

register.controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('thinkster.authentication.controllers')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

    function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication) {
        var vm = this;
        activate();

        vm.register = register;
        function register() {
            Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.username);
        }

        function activate() {
            if (Authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                $location.url('/');
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

authentication.service.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('thinkster.authentication.services')
        .factory('Authentication', Authentication);

    Authentication.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http'];

    function Authentication($cookies, $http) {
        var Authentication = {
            getAuthenticatedAccount: getAuthenticatedAccount,
            setAuthenticatedAccount: setAuthenticatedAccount,
            isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
            login: login,
            logout: logout,
            register: register,
            unauthenticate: unauthenticate
        };

        return Authentication;

        function register(email, password, username) {
            return $http.post('/api/v1/accounts', {
                email: email,
                password: password,
                username: username
            }).then(registerSuccessFn, registerErrorFn);

            function registerSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                Authentication.login(email, password);
            }

            function registerErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.error('Epic failure!');
            }
        }

        function login(email, password) {
            return $http.post('/api/v1/auth/login/', {
                email: email, password: password
            }).then(loginSuccessFn, loginErrorFn);

            function loginSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                Authentication.setAuthenticatedAccount(data.data);

                window.location = '/';
            }

            function loginErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.error('Epic failure!');
            }
        }

        function logout() {
            return $http.post('/api/v1/auth/logout/')
                .then(logoutSuccessFn, logoutErrorFn);

            function logoutSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                Authentication.unauthenticate();

                window.location = '/';
            }

            function logoutErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.error('Epic failure!');
            }
        }

        function getAuthenticatedAccount() {
            if (!$cookies.authenticatedAccount) {
                return;
            }

            return JSON.parse($cookies.authenticatedAccount);
        }

        function isAuthenticated() {
            return !!$cookies.authenticatedAccount;
        }

        function setAuthenticatedAccount(account) {
            $cookies.authenticatedAccount = JSON.stringify(account);
        }

        function unauthenticate() {
            delete $cookies.authenticatedAccount;
        }
    }
})();
```

I'm new to both Django & AnglarJS, so I don't know which part is causing the problem?

Comment: I'm not overly sure but try renaming the ```create``` function in your ```AccountViewSet``` class based view to ```post```

Comment: @Jordan Nope, i tried but still the same error.

Comment: create in AccountViewSet is correct. but i have 3 questions why are you implementing create in the serializer despite it has no custom behavior? and why are you implementing get permissions inside the view?? Why are you using routers when you have new routed methods in the view??

Comment: 1)The create function in the serializer, is for deserializating the data recieved from Authentication service in angularJS.

about the two other questions, i can't  really explain.
as i said i'm new to this, and you seem to understand these moving parts, so may be you can provide me with some guidance about where to implement the get_permissions and how to deal with the view ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need router in you url mapping, unless you have a customized action other than the following:

```py
    def list(self, request):
        pass

    def create(self, request):
        pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

add this to your **views.py**:

```py
account_list = AccountViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})
```

in **urls.py**:

```
 url(r'^account/$', account_list, name='account-list'),
```

Comment: for the account_list in the view, i get this error:
"name 'AccountViewSet' is not defined"

Comment: You have to add the following code under the definition of `AccountViewSet` that you shared above.

Comment: yes it's what i did, and i get the "NameError: name 'AccountViewSet' is not defined" Exception

Comment: `NameError Exception` means he can't find the definition, so check the spelling or maybe the indentation. `account_list` should be defined outside the class.

Comment: i doubled check the spelling, and the indentation is correct (i tried account_list both inside & outside the class definition.

i pushed my code to github so you can check it out.
https://github.com/soufiaane/CVC

and this is the Tutorial i was following so you get a good idea:
https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial

Comment: Add it after the class definition not before, or even put it at the end of the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98832/discussion-between-soufiane-mghanen-and-dhiatn).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with **urls.py**. Because `url(r'^.*$'...` comes before `url(r'^api/v1/`, Django simply discards the latter and routes the request to the `IndexView`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter similar error, sometimes it's just that the order of the URLs evaluation is not good. In this example, if you put `r""` first, `r"status"` cannot be found and will result in similar error like the OP.

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers

from subscription.views import SubscriptionViewSet, SubscriptionStatusViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"status", SubscriptionStatusViewSet)
router.register(r"", SubscriptionViewSet)

urlpatterns = [path("", include(router.urls))]
```

You can read more about how Django URLs work [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/).